# Read date time string in windows batch script

Tags: windows, datetime, batch-file, cmd

I have timestamps in the format 04-NOV-2015 23:16:33 in a text file. In a windows batch script, A for loop reads these strings using %%x. But 'echo %%x' displays only date without timestamp. Can we format the echo %%x to display timestamp as well ?

**Update: Existing for loop I have:**

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 skip=1" %%i in (inputfile.txt) do (
REM This input file has 4 columns of data. 4th column is the timestamp.
REM Hence have %%l after %%i, %%j, %%k below 
echo %%l
)
```

**Update :Solved.**

There was a problem with the SQL query that generated the timestamps in the input file. Well, I now changed the loop to "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" and treat date and time as separate entities for batch file to read.

Comment: Could you show the code you have to loop through the file here as well?

Comment: @DennisvanGils : Just added the for loop I have.

Comment: Could you show a complete line from the file?

Comment: nameofitem 1234 abcdef 12-30-2015 10:12:27. It had blank spaces so I did not use a delimiter in the for loop

Comment: Try using skip=3, tokens is 1,2, and output %%i and %%j

Comment: @DennisvanGils :Thank you for the help!

Comment: Will update my answer tomorrow, as I'm not currently on my pc but responding using my phone

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 usebackq tokens=4,5" %%x in ("timestamps.txt") do (
echo %%x %%y
)
pause
```

that should work

I'm guessing you used `tokens=1` and didn't specify `delims`, which causes the script to only print the part of the line before the first space

Comment: I'd wager he didn't specify any options at all; tokens defaults to 1 if it isn't specified.

Comment: Thank you for the help on this issue!

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the SQL query that generated the timestamps in the input file. Well, I now changed the loop to "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" and treat date and time as separate entities for batch file to read.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 skip=1" %%i in (inputfile.txt) do (

echo %%l %%m
)
```

Comment: A space is one of the deafault delimiters. So yes, the time is the 5th token.